# Trigger click event of plus button on google plus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-plus

I cant trigger event onClick of plus button in Google plus

[image]

I have try with a method:

[image]

But it didn't work.

The code I tried

```
    $(".mUbCce.fKz70d.GsLz7c.teCjMb.M9Bg4d").click()
```

I also noticed that when my mouse over the plus button, the mouse icon change to "hand-icon" but, I didn't find any CSS cursor for it.

Is there any magic from google ?

Thanks

Comment: Check event listener in console. Maybe you need to dispatch event instead

Comment: Could you post the code you tried to use, instead of providing an image?
that Notepad++ G+ post though: lol.

Comment: The code is very simple, as in the second image. I may lost of knowledge as @A. Wolff said. I am trying with dispatch event.

Comment: Text in images cannot be copied and pasted, cannot be searched. Please provide a text version of any code, example or logs.

Comment: Why not just use their [REST API](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/) rather than hacking their DOM, which will almost certainly change and break your code.

Comment: Thanks @JDB , I gonna the code in a [Chrome Extension](https://goo.gl/nFN9YN), It will be very easy if I can trigger click event on a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: Define a function fireEvent() like this:

```
    function fireEvent(node, eventName) {
    // Make sure we use the ownerDocument from the provided node to avoid cross-window problems
    var doc;
    if (node.ownerDocument) {
        doc = node.ownerDocument;
    } else if (node.nodeType == 9){
        // the node may be the document itself, nodeType 9 = DOCUMENT_NODE
        doc = node;
    } else {
        throw new Error("Invalid node passed to fireEvent: " + node.id);
    }

    if (node.dispatchEvent) {
        // Gecko-style approach (now the standard) takes more work
        var eventClass = "";

        // Different events have different event classes.
        // If this switch statement can't map an eventName to an eventClass,
        // the event firing is going to fail.
        switch (eventName) {
            case "click": // Dispatching of 'click' appears to not work correctly in Safari. Use 'mousedown' or 'mouseup' instead.
            case "mousedown":
            case "mouseup":
            eventClass = "MouseEvents";
            break;

            case "focus":
            case "change":
            case "blur":
            case "select":
            eventClass = "HTMLEvents";
            break;

            default:
            throw "fireEvent: Couldn't find an event class for event '" + eventName + "'.";
            break;
        }
        var event = doc.createEvent(eventClass);

        var bubbles = eventName == "change" ? false : true;
        event.initEvent(eventName, bubbles, true); // All events created as bubbling and cancelable.

        event.synthetic = true; // allow detection of synthetic events
        // The second parameter says go ahead with the default action
        node.dispatchEvent(event, true);
    } else  if (node.fireEvent) {
        // IE-old school style
        var event = doc.createEventObject();
        event.synthetic = true; // allow detection of synthetic events
        node.fireEvent("on" + eventName, event);
    }

};
```

And call

```
  fireEvent($0,"mousedown")
  fireEvent($0,"mouseup")
```

with $0 is the element you want to click